WPF item command not selected when displaying dialog
I would like to execute commands from a ComboBox. It works fine with MouseBinding to TextBlock. Nevertheless, it is the previous item (or nothing is none) which is selected when showing a dialog in the executed method.
I believe that the ComboBox item is actually selected (or more precisely displayed) at the end and because of the dialog, it leads to a loss of focus and the selected item is selected, but it does not display.
Does anyone can help me clarify and fix the issue? Should I use asynchronous commands to delay the execution after the ComboBox item is selected?
<ComboBox>

    <TextBlock Text="A">

        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ACommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
        </TextBlock.InputBindings>

    </TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Text="B">

        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding BCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
        </TextBlock.InputBindings>

    </TextBlock>

</ComboBox>

public ICommand ACommand => new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("A"), () => true);

public ICommand BCommand => new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("B"), () => true);

In the actual app, I use a dialog service and have the same issue both modal and modeless.
